# Index and match function on Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing, merge

I am new to Python and is currently working on a project that requires the usage of the software to perform some data cleansing tasks. I would like to know if it is feasible to perform excel-like index and match function on Python between two dataframes with different shapes.

Here's my idea

[image]

[image]

The values under column x in df1 is essentially part of the column header in df2 and they have both column y in common (duplicated values may appear in df1 but not df2). I would like to know if it is possible to update df2 by df1? e.g. df1["z"].iloc[0] is plugged into df2 row 0 and column a. Thx.

Comment: It is possible to update dataframes with new data, but your example does not require any updates. new example needed. and Please provide the input data as text. [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**New Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'x': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'], 'y': ['e', 'e', 'f', 'f', 'e'], 'z': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
data2 = {'y': ['e', 'f'], 'a': [1, 5], 'b': [2, 6], 'c': [3, 7], 'd': [4, 8]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

df1 & df2

```
    df1                        df2
    x   y   z            y   a    b    c    d
0   a   e   0       0    e   1    2    3    4
1   b   e   0       1    f   5    6    7    8
2   c   f   0   
3   d   f   0   
4   a   e   0
```

as you mentioned exist duplicated rows in df1

---

**Code**

```
out = df1.merge(df2.melt('y', var_name='x'), how='left')
```

out:

```
   x  y  z  value
0  a  e  0      1
1  b  e  0      2
2  c  f  0      7
3  d  f  0      8
4  a  e  0      1
```

value colum is update value of z column

If you want to replace the values in the z column with the values in the value column, you can use the following code:

```
out = df1.merge(df2.melt('y', var_name='x'), how='left').assign(z=lambda x: x.pop('value'))
```

out

```
   x  y  z
0  a  e  1
1  b  e  2
2  c  f  7
3  d  f  8
4  a  e  1
```